# Why does this FluentNHibernate query load everything?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have the following query:

```
MyRepository.Query<MyObject>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.AProperty == aValue);
```

It returns the correct MyObject, but it is starting to take more and more time.  When I looked with SQL Server Profiler I see that it loads **all** my MyObjects in the database, by selecting one and one row from the database for MyObject and related objects.  When the database grows this turns into thousands and thousands of selects for quite a simple query.

On the other hand, this query:

```
Session.QueryOver<MyObject>().Where(x => x.AProperty == aValue).SingleOrDefault<MyObject>()
```

does not load everything (it creates a single select statement instead of thousands).

Why?  Is there a way to tell Query not to load everything?  Or is this just how Linq-queries work?  The reason I ask is that I have an application where all queries are made using Query.  It will take some work to change it to QueryOver.  Any ideas?

Some details:

- *Query* is an extension method from the NHibernate.Linq namespace (NHibernate v 3.1.0.4000)
- My version of FluentNHibernate is 1.2.0.712
- I have this convention: Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this for over a day I finally realized the problem.  It is quite simple really, but hard to answer from the information in the question.  In case someone else experiences the same, here is the correct answer;

MyRepository has a method like this;

```
public List<T> Query<T>() where T : DomainEntity
{
    using (var session = _sessionSource.CreateSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = session.Query<T>();
            transaction.Commit();
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This means that I first **do** load everything (with `session.Query<T>()`), and only then query over the result (with `MyRepository.Query<MyObject>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.AProperty == aValue);`
.

Horribly bad, of course.  Copying others' code is not always smart ...

How to avoid it?  Just don't query a query.